# Taking screenshot in android app with appcelerator

Tags: android, screenshot, appcelerator

I'm trying to create button that would make screenshot and save it to gallery in my android app, but, I just cannot find any working code and always get some error. Does anyone know about working appcelerator code for getting screenshots? Right now my code is looking like this which is not working.

```
    $.btnScreen.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  Ti.Media.takeScreenshot(function(){
    var image = imgView.toBlob();
f =Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,"blog_image.jpg");
f.write(image);
});
```

This code gives me an error: imgView is not defined.
I'm also getting error that gallery cannot be created when I tried different code.

Comment: This looks pretty neat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android

Comment: I need code for appcelerator.

Comment: Alright, does this snippet help you?

`Ti.Media.takeScreenshot(function(e){
        Ti.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(e.media);
    });`

Comment: With this code:$.btnScreen.addEventListener("click",function(){
Ti.Media.takeScreenshot(function(e){
    Ti.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(e.media);
});
}); Im getting error: Failed to create application gallery directory.

Comment: Does it work now with your new code?

Comment: no getting error Failed to create application gallery directory.

Comment: That's super weird...

Comment: Do you have write permissions to your external storage?
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>

Comment: I have added it to tiapp.xml in <manifest> like this:   `code`<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <manifest>
            <application android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar"/>
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        </manifest>
    </android>`code` but still getting: Failed to create application gallery directory.

Comment: Which version of Android are you testing on and what is the Titanium SDK version you are using?

Comment: android 6.0, SDK is 5.3.1.GA

Comment: Ok im finally getting screenshots after giving permission to my app by hand in my device. For some reason, the app has permissions denied by default in my device. Is there a way how to change this in appcelerator? I cannot release my app if users had first to change permissions in settings.